# Redirecting all requests to index.php without direct access

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following code in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This redirects all requests to index.php. However I am still able to access www.mydomain.com/index.php directly from the URL. As www.mydomain.com servers the same content as www.mydomain.com/index.php will this be recorded as duplicated in google, if so how do I prevent it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert this rule before existing rule to remove `index.php` from URI:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```